# C# SQL Select Query only dump one column

Tags: c#, sql, select

I am stuck in connecting SQL and run a simple select query,  I need to output `select * from ServerInfo  where ServerID = 1991638835"` to either console line or txt file:

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;

namespace ConnectingToSQLC
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("server= XXXXX; database = ES1Archive; Integrated Security=false; User ID = sa; Password=XXXXXX");
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from ServerInfo  where ServerID = 1991638835", conn);

            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader ();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
            //Console.WriteLine ("{1}", "{0}", reader.GetString (0), reader.GetString (1));
                Console.WriteLine(reader.GetString(3));
            }
            reader.Close();
            conn.Close();

            if (Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                Console.ReadLine(); 
            }

      }
    }
}
```

It's working fine. But if I changed to 
`Console.WriteLine ("{1}", "{3}", reader.GetString (1), reader.GetString (3));`  I always have column 2. In total, there are 7 columns and column 3 is empty while column 4 is a XML.

How can I modify my code to dump all?

Comment: What's the format of the table?

Answer (score 3):

You've got too many formatting strings - combine them into a single one, e.g.:

```
Console.WriteLine ("{0} - {1}", reader.GetString(1), reader.GetString(3))
```

The indexes to the formatting string of the `Console.WriteLine` [overload you are using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/828t9b9h(v=vs.110).aspx) is like `string.Format` - it isn't dependent on *which* indexes you use in the reader, the format argument placeholders just need to match the *order* of the other `params args` parameters.

Also:

- It is bad practice to use `SELECT *` in general, and even more dangerous when you are accessing data reader columns by ordinal index, as a change in the table will break your reader code. Suggest instead that you explicitly name the columns you are using and / or use the column name accessor to the `reader`
- If the only use for the reader is for the string output on `Console.WriteLine`, you won't need to use the `Get<Type>()` overload - you can simply use the ordinal accessor (after you've guaranteed the order of the columns with the explicit column name `SELECT` :-)

e.g. for reader columns 1, 3 and 6 (Zero based of course):

```
Console.WriteLine ("{0} - {1} - {2}", reader[1], reader[3], reader[6]);
```

But better still:

```
Console.WriteLine ("{0} - {1} - {2}", reader["RealNameOfCol1"], 
                                      reader["RealNameOfCol3"], reader["RealNameOfCol6"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a loop with IDataRecord interface:

```
class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("server= XXXXX; database = ES1Archive; Integrated Security=false; User ID = sa; Password=XXXXXX");
       conn.Open();
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from ServerInfo  where ServerID = 1991638835", conn);

       SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader ();
       while (reader.Read())
       {
            for(int i = 0; i<reader.FieldCount;i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(reader[i]);
            }
       }
       reader.Close();
       conn.Close();

       if (Debugger.IsAttached)
       {
           Console.ReadLine(); 
       }

 }
}
```

Comment: You don't have to cast to `IDataRecord` to use `FieldCount` and the indexer.